# how to pass arguments on window functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function(){
    var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    window[fn]();
});

function goUp() {
    console.log('up');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-fn='goUp'>lorem</div>
```

The above works but I need some arguments on `goUp` function.  For example:

```
<div class='title' data-fn="goUp('gold')">lorem</div>  

function goUp(item) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Expecting `gold` in console but I'm getting error.

Any help?

Comment: Do you really need to store function calls in the HTML? That's probably not a good idea, for the same reason we don't use `onclick` any more.

Comment: Use a `data-arguments="gold"` and pass that (either always as a string, or use JSON values right away). Also, you should pass the event object and current target element to the function that you're calling - which would allow `goUp` to fetch arbitrary information from the element as well.

Comment: @Bergi, excuse me, can't understand the second part of your comment (`you should pass...` could you write a code, pls

Comment: Use `function(e){
 var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
 window[fn].call(this, e);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any binding your code. The only reference is the string in `data-fn`, which as I said it's just a string!

You use JQuery to obtain that string, and look for any property in the `window` object with that key. If you find it, then you execute the function.

That's not different by:

```
const foo = "bar";
window.bar = "hello world";
console.log(window[foo]); // hello world
```

And as you understood, your html has no clue about if data-fn is a function or not, if it has parameters or not.

However, you can add a further attribute and use it as parameter:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function() {
  var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
  var arg1 = $(this).attr('data-arg1');
  window[fn](arg1);
});

function goUp(arg){
  console.log('up', arg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-fn='goUp' data-arg1="gold">lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string manipulation, you could remove the arguments from the function name, and then use apply to call the function with those. This would require the function name be present (as would other implementations) and would also require the arguments to be strings (as would other implementations).

Find the position of the parens using indexOf, and form the required values using substring.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function(){
    var val = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    var openParen = val.indexOf('(');
    var fn = val.substring(0,openParen);
    var args = val.substring(openParen+1,val.indexOf(')')).split(',');
    window[fn].apply({},args);
});

function goUp(item){
    console.log(item);
}
function multi(a,b){
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-fn="goUp('gold')">lorem</div>  
<div class='title' data-fn="multi('red','blue')">ipsum</div>
```